# QT use unzip on OS X

Tags: macos, qt

I'm trying to unzip from within my application. I only need this to work on OS X.

For some reason I cannot get this to unzip my file:

```
QProcess *proc = new QProcess( this );
proc->start("unzip", QStringList("testFile.zip"));
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What error does it give? What version of QT are you using?

Comment: Im using QT5, not getting any output

Comment: What output are you expecting and from where? You need to connect to the QProcess error signal. I suspect either or both unzip and testFile.zip can't be found, as the working directory is not the one you think it is, or unzip is not defined in your environment path.

Comment: I'm getting this error: `QIODevice::read: device not open`

Comment: How are you getting that error? Are you trying to call another function, such as readAllStandardOutput, or is that in a slot that you've connected to the error signal from QProcess?

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you can try.
1. Instead of "unzip", use "/usr/bin/unzip", ie, provide the full path of the program. 
2. Use one big string, not string list. Like this:

```
 proc->start("/usr/bin/unzip testFile.zip");
```

Answer (score 1):

If someone is still interested my solution:

```
QString path = "/tmp/testFile.zip";
QProcess unzip;
unzip.setWorkingDirectory("/tmp/"); // set working directory - for extraction
unzip.start("unzip", QStringList() << "-o" << path); // overwrite files
if (!unzip.waitForFinished()) return; // wait for finished here

QByteArray result = unzip.readAll(); // read the result
unzip.close(); // close the process
qDebug() << result; // debug the result
```